# Error AWS WAFv2 web ACL managed rules when created with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

I want to create an AWS WAFv2 web acl of Cloudfront scope. I am using AWS managed rules. For Some rules in the managed rule group I have a scop-down statement. The json that I get from AWS is as follows:

```
{
  "Name": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Statement": {
    "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
      "VendorName": "AWS",
      "Name": "AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet",
      "ScopeDownStatement": {
        "ByteMatchStatement": {
          "SearchString": "abc",
          "FieldToMatch": {
            "UriPath": {}
          },
          "TextTransformations": [
            {
              "Priority": 0,
              "Type": "NONE"
            }
          ],
          "PositionalConstraint": "CONTAINS_WORD"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "OverrideAction": {
    "Count": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
  }
}
```

The AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-scope-down-statements.html) says that scope-down statements are allowed in the Managed rule group statement. However, when I read the Terraform docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl#managed-rule-group-statement) we don’t have any option for scope-down statements. When I try to create a rule like the following, it passes terraform validation, however when I apply it I get an AWS error that says that I have added two statements, where one is required. This is very confusing. Is there a way I can achieve this, if yes how? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
rule                                {
    name                            = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
    priority                        = 0
    override_action                 {
        count                       {}
    }
    statement                       {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
            name                    = "AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
            vendor_name             = "AWS"
        }                      {
        byte_match_statement {
            field_to_match   { 
                uri_path     {}
            }
            search_string    = "abc"
            text_transformation {
                priority        = 0
                type            = "NONE"
            }
            positional_constraint = "CONTAINS_WORD"
        }
    }
    visibility_config               {
        sampled_requests_enabled    = true
        metric_name                 = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled  = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by upgrading the `aws` provider version to `3.52.0`. I added the following:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
aws = {
  source = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = "3.52.0"
    }
  }
}
```

The rule now looks as follows:

```
rule                                {
    name                            = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
    priority                        = 0
    override_action                 {
        count                       {}
    }
    statement                       {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
            name                    = "AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
            vendor_name             = "AWS"
            scope_down_statement    {
                byte_match_statement {
                    field_to_match {
                        uri_path   {}
                    }
                    search_string  = "abc"
                    text_transformation {
                        priority   = 0
                        type       = "NONE"
                    }
                    positional_constraint = "CONTAINS_WORD"
                }
            }
        }                      
    }
    visibility_config               {
        sampled_requests_enabled    = true
        metric_name                 = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled  = true
    }
}
```